# How do I get MSMQ performance counters?

Tags: c#, msmq, performancecounter

I have a bunch of MSMQs that I have created programatically using MessageQueue.Create(path) but when I look in perfmon I don't see those queue instances listed, only queues I created manually are listed. How do I get perf counters for all the queues?

Comment: Are you sure the were successfully created?  I've created queues programmatically and they showed up in perfmon as expected.

Comment: Yes I'm seeing the queues just not the counters for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that even though the queues are persisted beyond the life of the application that created them, if you restart the machine or the MSMQ service, the perfcounters for the queues that were created programatically are not created until the program creates an instance of the queue (using the MessageQueue constructor this time)